# anchor tag data not accessible when clicking on glyphicons inside the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get the data when there is only a glyphicon in the anchor tag? Below is a demonstration of the problem...

http://jsfiddle.net/sua0yp4y/2/

HTML:

```
<h1 id="output1">OUTPUT1</h1>
<h1 id="output2">OUTPUT2</h1>
<a class="withIcon" href="#" data-taskid="1123" data-userid="5813"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a>

<h1 id="output3">OUTPUT3</h1>
<h1 id="output4">OUTPUT4</h1>
<a class="withoutIcon" href="#" data-taskid="1123" data-userid="5813">without icon</a>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click','a.withIcon',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("h1#output1").text($(e.target).data('userid'));
    $("h1#output2").text($(e.target).data('taskid'));
});

$('body').on('click','a.withoutIcon',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("h1#output3").text($(e.target).data('userid'));
    $("h1#output4").text($(e.target).data('taskid'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the closest('a') to find the closest anchor tag and get the data values:

```
$("h1#output1").text($(e.target).closest('a').data('userid'));
    $("h1#output2").text($(e.target).closest('a').data('taskid'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sua0yp4y/3/

Comment: Interestingly, this is the answer that works most consistently. The other answers work only some of the time. I believe this issue has to do with JQuery rather than Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The user clicks over the image you can change the event:

```
$('body').on('click','.glyphicon',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("h1#output1").text($(e.target).parent().data('userid'));
    $("h1#output2").text($(e.target).parent().data('taskid'));
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sua0yp4y/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` instead of `e.target` to referece the element you clicked on.

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sua0yp4y/5/

```
$('body').on('click','a.withIcon',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("h1#output1").text($(this).data('userid'));
    $("h1#output2").text($(this).data('taskid'));
});

$('body').on('click','a.withoutIcon',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("h1#output3").text($(this).data('userid'));
    $("h1#output4").text($(this).data('taskid'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

replace $(e.target) with $(this) your problem get resolved.

```
demo http://jsfiddle.net/sua0yp4y/8/
```